# How to disable mouse wheel from this site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a website and I want disable mouse wheel from [this site](https://www.lavisite360.fr/logiciel/dvisite/bc7c3ec03de152d5).

```html
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="author" content="drive visite">
    <meta name="copyright" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="Visite virtuelle 360 by drive visite logiciel panoramique">
    <title>Drive visite 360 </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/css/font-awesome.min.css'; ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/css/style.css'; ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'lib/tooltipster/css/tooltipster.bundle.min.css'; ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'lib/tooltipster/css/plugins/tooltipster/sidetip/themes/tooltipster-sidetip-borderless.min.css'; ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'lib/lightslider/lightslider.css'; ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'lib/jssocials/jssocials.css'; ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'lib/jssocials/jssocials-theme-plain-color.css'; ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'lib/idvisite/ivisitepano.css'; ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'lib/idvisite/idvisite.theme.visitepano.css'; ?>">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="fstpn-ui-page">
      <div class="fstpn-ui-dvisite-wrap">
        <div class="fstpn-ui-dvisite" id="dvisite"></div>
        <?php if(sizeOf($scenes) > 1) { ?>
        <div id="dvisite-slider-wrap" class="fstpn-ui-dvisite-slider-wrap fstpn-ui-hidden">
          <div class="fstpn-ui-dvisite-slider-toggle fstpn-ui-hidden"></div>
          <ul id="dvisite-slider" class="fstpn-ui-dvisite-slider">
            <?php foreach($scenes as $key => $scene) { ?><?php $imageThumb = ($scene['imageThumb']['url'] ? $scene['imageThumb'] : $scene['image']); ?>
            <li>
              <div class="fstpn-ui-dvisite-slider-thumb" data-scene="<?php echo 'scene' . $key; ?>" <?php echo 'scene' . $key; ?> <?php echo ($scene['title'] ? 'title="' . $scene['title'] . '"' : '') ?>><img src="<?php echo ($imageThumb['isCustom'] ? $imageThumb['url'] : $uploadUrl . $imageThumb['url']); ?>" alt=""></div>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div id="dvisite-share-wrap" class="fstpn-ui-dvisite-share-wrap">
          <div id="dvisite-share" class="fstpn-ui-dvisite-share"></div>
          <div id="dvisite-embed" class="jssocials-share jssocials-share-embed"><a href="#" class="jssocials-share-link"><i class="fa fa-code jssocials-share-logo"></i><span class="jssocials-share-label">Int&eacute;grer</span></a></div>
          <br/><input id="dvisite-embed-code" class="fstpn-ui-dvisite-embed-code" value="<iframe width='560' height='315' src='<?php echo current_url() ?>' allowfullscreen frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   
    <script src="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/js/lib/jquery.min.js'; ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/js/view.js'; ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url() . 'lib/tooltipster/js/tooltipster.bundle.min.js'; ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url() . 'lib/lightslider/lightslider.min.js'; ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url() . 'lib/jssocials/jssocials.min.js'; ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url() . 'lib/idvisite/three.min.js'; ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url() . 'lib/idvisite/jquery.idvisite.js'; ?>"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery( document ).ready(function( jQuery ) {
  jQuery('#dvisite').idvisite({
   theme: 'ipnrm-theme-visitepano',
   autoLoad: true,
   autoRotate: true,
   autoRotateSpeed: 0.001,
   showZoomCtrl:false ,
   showShareCtrl: true,
   showAutoRotateCtrl: true,
   pitchLimits: true,
   sceneId: 'scene0',
   scenes: {
     
  <?php foreach($scenes as $key => $scene) { ?>
  <?php echo 'scene' . $key; ?> : {
       type  : 'sphere',
       image : '
  <?php echo ($scene['image']['isCustom'] ? $scene['image']['url'] : $uploadUrl . $scene['image']['url']); ?>',
       title : '
  <?php echo ($scene['title']); ?>',
       yaw   : 
  <?php echo ($scene['yaw'] !== null ? $scene['yaw'] : 0); ?>,
       pitch : 
  <?php echo ($scene['pitch'] !== null ? $scene['pitch'] : 0); ?>,
       zoom  : 
  <?php echo ($scene['zoom'] !== null && $scene['zoom'] >= 0 && $scene['zoom'] <= 75 ? $scene['zoom'] :75); ?>
      },
     
  <?php } ?>
    },
    onSceneChange: function(oldSceneId, newSceneId) {
     jQuery('.fstpn-ui-dvisite-slider-thumb').removeClass('fstpn-ui-active');
     jQuery('.fstpn-ui-dvisite-slider-thumb[data-scene="' + newSceneId + '"]').addClass('fstpn-ui-active');
    },
    onShare: function(e) {
     jQuery("#dvisite-share-wrap").toggleClass('fstpn-ui-active');
    }
   });
   
   var $el = jQuery('#dvisite-slider-wrap').detach();
   jQuery('#dvisite .ipnrm-controls').append($el);
   
   jQuery('#dvisite-slider').lightSlider({
    autoWidth:true,
    loop:false,
    pager:false,
    gallery:true,
    onSliderLoad: function() {
     jQuery('.fstpn-ui-dvisite-slider-wrap').removeClass('fstpn-ui-hidden');
     jQuery('.fstpn-ui-dvisite-slider-toggle').removeClass('fstpn-ui-hidden');
    }
   });
   
   jQuery('.fstpn-ui-dvisite-slider-toggle').on('click', function() {
    var $sliderWrap = jQuery('.fstpn-ui-dvisite-slider-wrap');
    $sliderWrap.toggleClass('fstpn-ui-hidden');
   });
   
   jQuery('.fstpn-ui-dvisite-slider-thumb').on('click', function() {
    var sceneId = jQuery(this).data("scene");
    if (sceneId) {
     jQuery('#dvisite').idvisite("loadscene", {sceneId: sceneId});
    }
   });
   
   jQuery('.fstpn-ui-dvisite-slider-thumb').tooltipster({
    parent: '#dvisite .ipnrm-controls',
    theme: 'tooltipster-borderless',
    animation: 'grow'
   });
   
   var $el = jQuery('#dvisite-share-wrap').detach();
   jQuery('#dvisite .ipnrm-controls').append($el);
   
   $("#dvisite-share").jsSocials({
    text: 'Visite 360.',
    showLabel:true,
    showCount:true,
    shareIn:'popup',
    shares: ['email', 'twitter', 'facebook']
   });
   
   var $el = $("#dvisite-embed").detach();
   $el.on("click", function() {
    $("#dvisite-embed-code").toggleClass("fstpn-ui-active");
   });
   $("#dvisite-share .jssocials-shares").append($el);
  });
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e)
{
    //ctrl key is pressed
    if(e.ctrlKey == true)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        //Your logic here
        console.log("Zoom Feature Disabled. ctrl+Mousewheel Pressed");        
    }
});
 
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `idvisite` has an option called `mouseWheelZoom`. Set it to `false` to disable zooming on mouse wheel

Comment: its working thanks Dear :D

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("body").on("mousewheel", function() { return false; });
```